# Constructor that takes and array and a list of values

Tags: arrays, vector

These are the instructions that I should follow:

Vector class: holds a vector of real numbers as a one dimensional array.
Constructors:
(1) Takes an array of doubles and convert to a Vector
(2) Takes a comma separated doubles as a list and convert them into a Vector.

```
package p1;

public class Vector {

  double yourArray[]=new double[4];

  public Vector(double yourArray[]){
    this.yourArray=yourArray;

  }
}
```

What is the difference between comma separated doubles as a list and an array of doubles? Aren't they same thing? If not, how can I write this code in my Vector class?

Comment: So, can you tell the difference between `new Vector(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)` and `new Vector(myDoubleArray)`? (Assuming that `myDoubleArray` is of type `double[]`.)

Comment: what? i don't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code needs to accomodate both of the following constructor invocations:

```
Vector myVector = new Vector(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0);
```

and

```
double[] myArray = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0};
Vector myVector = new Vector(myArray);
```

If you can create a `Vector` using either of those two constructor patterns, you win. That's what it's asking for.

You can do that with the following constructor signature:

```
public class Vector {
  double[] yourArray;

  public Vector(double... yourArray) {
    this.yourArray = yourArray;
  }
}
```

The variable arguments pattern with the three dots ("double... yourArray") actually translates under the covers to an array ("double[] yourArray"). So you can accomodate both invocation patterns with a single constructor.

Comment: but what if it says duplicate myVector in test class?

Comment: but how can i create matrix with this seperated two one dimension arrays?

Comment: In your test class you are probably declaring `myVector` twice. Either use more than one test method, or pick a different variable name.

Comment: A 2-dimensional matrix could be represented by an array of this `Vector`, like this: `Vector[] aMatrix;`.

Comment: but where should i put this Vector[] aMatrix? in test class or matrix?

Comment: Perhaps you could post a new question about that so we all could understand what you're trying to do with it.